# List IndexOf return -1 even though there's a matching object c#

Tags: c#, list, indexof

I have the following code to find the index of the `ColorItem` object in a `List<ColorItem>`

```
//Get the index of the color item
var colorList = dialogViewModel.Items;
var colorItem = new ColorItem();
colorItem = sp.TileColorItem;
int index = colorList.IndexOf(colorItem);
```

Even though there's a matching object in the list, `index` always returns -1. What am I missing?

[image: colorList content]

[image: colorItem content]

Comment: There are two colorItems with the same value, but they are different objects. One *is* in the list, the other one *isn't*.

Comment: Is `ColorItem` your own class? If so, you can make it work by overriding `Equals`... but we'll need the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning `colorItem` to `sp.TileColorItem`, which is not in `colorList`. Thats why if you call `colorList.IndexOf(colorItem)` it returns `-1`.
You may want to use something like this:

```
int index;
foreach (var item in colorList)
{
    if (item.Text == sp.TileColorItem)
    {
        index = colorList.IndexOf(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: nope. Probably the easiest would be to loop through the list (with a loop counter) and return, when the color values are equal.

Comment: No, I don't think this is the best approach. If these are meant to be treated as values where distinct objects can be viewed as equal, it would make sense to override Equals to make `IndexOf` work. At that point, you could also use it as a dictionary key, etc. I'd only manually loop like this if the class concerned weren't under my control.

Comment: @JonSkeet you probably right, but I believe that for beginners it's much easier to loop the `List` to find the value instead of doing a tricky things like overriding. If project is small there is no need to override `Equals` method of `ColorItem` class (which can be a part of third-party framework)

Comment: @AndreyGordeev: Whereas I believe that it's worth explaining what's going on instead, and at least giving the option. Otherwise the OP will believe that they *can't* do what they want, and could easily get confused when `IndexOf` works for other classes. Even if you *are* going to loop, I probably wouldn't *then* loop again by using `IndexOf`, but use a counter instead.

Answer (score 8):

`List<T>.IndexOf` looks for an item in the list which is *equal* to the value you pass it. By default, for classes, equality is simply object identity - so two different objects are treated as unequal, whatever their fields are. However, you can change this by overriding the `Equals` method.

If `ColorItem` is your own class, you can definitely make this work, by overriding `Equals` (and `GetHashCode`; which isn't used by `List<T>.IndexOf`, but should always be overridden to be consistent with `Equals`) appropriately:

```
public sealed class ColorItem : IEquatable<ColorItem>
{
    private readonly string text;
    private readonly Color color;

    public string Text { get { return text; } }
    public Color Color { get { return color; } }

    public ColorItem(string text, Color color)
    {
        this.text = text;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return Equals(other as ColorItem);
    }

    public bool Equals(ColorItem otherItem)
    {
        if (otherItem == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return otherItem.Text == text && otherItem.Color == color;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 19;
        hash = hash * 31 + (text == null ? 0 : text.GetHashCode());
        hash = hash * 31 + color.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Now `IndexOf` should work fine.

(I've implemented `IEquatable<ColorItem>` for good measure, as general good practice. It's not strictly necessary here though.)